# Connection of a centOS with Amazon EC-2 Linux instance in Ansible

Tags: amazon-ec2, ssh, centos, ansible

I have been trying to ping my client-1 (CentOS  in VirtualBox) in ansible master (Amazon EC-2 Linux) instance, but it is showing this error:

[image: Input 1]

I have tried connecting another Amazon EC-2 Linux instance (client-2) and it is working fine.

Comment: You're trying to ping from amazon cloud to your local PC with 10.* address? That's not going to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is:

> ssh connection to 10.0.2.15 timed out

Before you proceed with Ansible make sure ssh connection works. Details are available in [Network Debug and Troubleshooting Guide](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/network/user_guide/network_debug_troubleshooting.html). If other instance works fine find what's different.